# How to configure my laptop wireless adapter for DHCPv6

Tags: arch-linux, ip, ipv6, netctl

The network topology is as simple as it gets: [image: network topology]

After some correspondence my ISP flipped some switch to enable the router to get what the router calls a "Default IPv6 Gateway." My Ethernet-connected PC can now use IPv6 without issue:

```
$ ping -q -c 1 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(syd15s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:806::200e)) 56 data bytes

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 45.496/45.496/45.496/0.000 ms
```

The laptop, running [the same software](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root) on the same distro (Arch Linux), is able to connect to IPv4 hosts but not IPv6 ones:

```
$ ping -q -c 1 ipv6.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When asking my ISP about this they responded

> Do you have IPv6 configured on the wireless adapter in the computer?

How can I tell? The closest I can think if is that the laptop seems to have assigned an internal IP to the network interface:

```
$ ip address show dev wlp1s0 
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:8c:a0:52:3e:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f0ac:8fe:bb0d:619a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

My laptop does not have an Ethernet plug, so I can't check whether it would receive an IPv6 address via Ethernet.

---

The closest page I can think of in the router configuration is this:

[image: IPv6 LAN auto configuration page]

---

I've been in touch further with my ISP, and they maintain that with the current settings it *should* just work. **I just connected to the wireless network with my desktop PC and can confirm that it does indeed receive a DHCPv6 lease.**

---

Both machines have identical /etc/dhcpcd.conf and /etc/netconfig files (confirmed using `diff -u <(ssh laptop cat /etc/…) /etc/…`). Even so, when connecting to Wi-Fi the dhcpcd log is very different. On my PC:

```
$ journalctl --follow --output=cat --unit=dhcpcd | grep ^eno1
eno1: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.2
eno1: leased 192.168.1.2 for 86400 seconds
eno1: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
eno1: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
eno1: soliciting an IPv6 router
eno1: Router Advertisement from xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
eno1: adding address xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64
eno1: adding route to xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
eno1: adding default route via xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
eno1: soliciting a DHCPv6 lease
```

On the laptop:

```
$ journalctl --follow --output=cat --unit=dhcpcd | grep ^wlp1s0
wlp1s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.6
wlp1s0: leased 192.168.1.6 for 86400 seconds
wlp1s0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
wlp1s0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
wlp1s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
wlp1s0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

---

Their Wi-Fi connection configuration is also identical except for the interface name:

```
Description='Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu'
Interface=wlo1
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
ESSID=…
IP=dhcp
Key=…
```

---

Wireshark reports that the laptop does indeed receive an ICMPv6 router advertisement from the correct MAC address, supporting the idea that the problem is with the laptop not handling the router advertisement.

---

Diffing the IP tables of the two machines seems to have given a clue: There are some rules left over since a UFW installation years ago on my laptop. Diffing the IP tables of the two machines shows this:

```
$ comm -23 <(ssh laptop cat iptable.txt) iptable.txt 
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
…
```

I guess the `-P INPUT DROP` could be responsible for this issue? IPv6 tables show similar differences:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-N ufw6-after-forward
-N ufw6-after-input
-N ufw6-after-logging-forward
-N ufw6-after-logging-input
-N ufw6-after-logging-output
-N ufw6-after-output
-N ufw6-before-forward
-N ufw6-before-input
-N ufw6-before-logging-forward
-N ufw6-before-logging-input
-N ufw6-before-logging-output
-N ufw6-before-output
-N ufw6-logging-allow
-N ufw6-logging-deny
-N ufw6-reject-forward
-N ufw6-reject-input
-N ufw6-reject-output
-N ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw6-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw6-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw6-track-forward
-N ufw6-track-input
-N ufw6-track-output
-N ufw6-user-forward
-N ufw6-user-input
-N ufw6-user-limit
-N ufw6-user-limit-accept
-N ufw6-user-logging-forward
-N ufw6-user-logging-input
-N ufw6-user-logging-output
-N ufw6-user-output
```

Comment: Can the laptop use IPv6 if you connect it via ethernet cable?  Is your PC getting its IPv6 prefix from ISP equpment, or via router advertisements from your own equipment with a delegated `/64` ?   The `fe80::/64` address on `wlp1s0` is a _link-local_ address, used only for communication on the local broadcast domain.  You'll see a similar address on your working PC, in addition to it's global IPv6 address[es], probably starting `200x:...`

Comment: IPv6 prefix refers to the initial (64) bits of your IPv6 address.  It might help if you add the topology.  Is the (working) PC connected directly to ISP equipment?  Or to a SOHO router you own and manage?  Is the laptop connected via the same equipment?

Comment: The laptop does seem to have IPv6 enabled and working on the wireless adapter, since it has a link-local IPv6 address. The problem seems to be that you are not getting a routable IPv6 address on the wireless interface. The way this works is that the router periodically sends multicast router advertisements which the hosts on the network use to autoconfigure their IPv6 addresses. Maybe the router isn't sending these on the wireless interface? Is the router functioning as a wifi access point or do you have a separate access point? If separate, does it pass through the router advertisements?

Comment: How is your networking configured? Post the relevant configuration files.

Comment: I never have managed to get the autoconfiguration working on my router and instead enabled the router's DHCP6 feature.  For mean that meant going into the router's settings and switching from to "persistent" IPv6 addresses.  After that ally my devices suddenly used IPv6 when they could.

Comment: with reading only parts of your Q ;-), do you have some special firewall/iptable rules on your laptop? If you have some draconic filter, you should let ipv6-icmp through explicitly (and port 546, if you want prefix delegation to work).

Comment: tl;dr are you blocking ipv6-icmp in your firewall? notice that icmp != ipv6-icmp.

Comment: @UncleBilly I've added the ip6?tables differences; you might be onto something!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr The fix:

1. [Completely reset the iptables rules and chains](https://serverfault.com/a/200642/11292)
2. Re-apply the [firewall setup](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root)

This was caused by a combination of things:

1. `-P INPUT DROP` in my iptables rules left over from earlier work on securing the system.
2. Mistaken assumption that [the Puppet firewall "purge" directive](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/firewall#create-firewall-rules) would completely reset the firewall. We all know what assumptions do…

Thank you all very much for the help! Specially to [@UncleBilly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525348/how-to-configure-my-laptop-wireless-adapter-for-dhcpv6/526017#comment973119_525348) for asking about differences in firewall rules.